# SQL Server CE database size issue

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I have an application from a company that went out of business. It appears to use the SQL Server CE database. I have searched the system and can't find any `.sdf` files. It appears that the database has grown too big. Any idea how I can find the DB and change the maximum size?

ERROR message:

> Unable to log application start. 
>   - System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException:  An error occurred
>   while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner
>   exception for details. --->
>
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException:  The database file is larger
>   than the configured maximum database size.  This setting takes effect
>   on the first concurrent database connection only.  [ Required Max
>   Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) = 257 ]

Comment: .sqf - typo or error for .sdf?

Answer (score 11):

You need to locate the connection string and add: Max Database Size=1024

(Max is 4000)